# Upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 failed - unable to login

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade

Yesterday i updgraded from **10.04 to 12.04** via the update-manager. At the end it said `"Failed to upgrade due to too many errors".`
Before that i got a lot of error messages that said packages could ne configured - they were all related to **mono.**

Then it force me to restart. When booting now, I see the pink screen (without logo). After that it turns black and the cursor appears. Then its flashing around between being bright and dark and showing the cursor and not showing it. But no way i see the login-screen.

At the moment i am not able to boot from usb since my usb device is too large to be formated to FAT-32 (8GB).

This all is happening on this machine:
AMD E-350 Processor (2x1,65Ghz)
4GB DDR3 RAM
320GB SATA II Hard drive
AMD® Radeon™ HD 6320

Thanks in advance to everyone who trys helping me ;) I have to continue working with data from this machine so i´d be pleased to get my data accessible.

Greets ;)

Answer (score 0):

This method should help you save your data: Use a bootable CD from any Linux distribution (Debian, Ubuntu, Arch, Knoppix, etc) and use it to boot from the CD/DVD drive. You should be able to find a "try" operating system option that does not disturb data on the hard disk. After booting attach a portable external drive and backup your data.

Comment: I tried this with puppy linux and it did not work it says `"Remove device. Press any key to reboot"`

Comment: Try with Ubuntu/Kubuntu [live CD].